# What is the best practise for android development and the coding pattern

Tags: android

i'm new in android development but, i don't get the coding pattern in android studio, now i see a youtube tutorial using the traditional xml for the layout, but there's other tutorial that use jetpack compose and using the mvvm, please guide me for my development stage in android. or any tutorial that can use in my coding journey in android development , thank you so much